# consul behind traefik with context path

Tags: traefik, consul

I want to deploy consul and allow for admins to monitor list of registered services using ui.
Also I need to allow access from intranet (local network) for this UI but it must be behind context-path (say, 'front-ui/***')

here is my setup: docker-compose file used to deploy stack:

```yaml
  consul:
    image: "consul:1.12.3"
    command: ["agent", "-dev", "-client", "0.0.0.0", "-ui-content-path", "/front-ui/consul"]
    deploy:
      labels:
        traefik.enable: "true"
        traefik.http.routers.router-consul-http.entrypoints: "http"
        traefik.http.routers.router-consul-http.middlewares: "consul-auth"
        traefik.http.routers.router-consul-http.rule: "PathPrefix(`/front-ui/consul`)"
        traefik.http.routers.router-consul-http.service: "consul@docker"
        traefik.http.services.consul.loadbalancer.server.port: 8500
        traefik.http.middlewares.consul-auth.basicauth.users: "bla-bla"
        traefik.docker.network: "proxy"
    networks:
      - proxy
```

after this I try to access consul ui via url "http://my-site/front-ui/consul"  and it works partially.
i.e. if I open html code of the page I see that it uses correct urls

```html
  <link rel="icon" href="/front-ui/consul/assets/favicon.ico">
  <link rel="icon" href="/front-ui/consul/assets/favicon.svg" type="image/svg+xml">
  <link rel="apple-touch-icon" href="/front-ui/consul/assets/apple-touch-icon-01cd4680782fbb5bc02301347df9903d.png">
```

but then consul ui makes http call to rest api to load list of whatever it needs and url is not correct

```
http://bla-bla/v1/catalog/datacenters
```

so I am at loss.

How is it even supposed to work if setting "-ui-content-path" affects only urls of html/css resources and not accessible rest api ?
and opposite question if there is setting to change url for rest api then how to configure it for clients that expect to access it using 8500 port ?

i googled through consul doc and found nothing which is disappointing as described by me use case looks quite common.

Comment: You need to add reverse proxy in front of consul, like nginx, and manipulate the request. ui-content-path is a path in consul config directory, that contains custom template to be shown, not address path.

Comment: actually traefik already serves as reverse proxy, 
i just don't want to add into into its rules all urls that rest api maybe called from consul ui, and i think that this is a quite natural desire not to mess with internals of consul (which maybe a subject of change at without notice)